# How to copy .json file stored in azure devOps repo to azure storage account as a blob?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

There is a filed which is stored in repository in azure devOps. I want to transfer that file to the azure storage account on daily basis. Is there any way, we can do that?

Lets suppose File name is Hack.json and stored on a path in github repo : Azure-Models/samples/src/Hack.json and we want to store it in storage account container with name samples.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pipeline with [schedule with defined cron](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) and [AzureFileCopy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-file-copy?view=azure-devops)

```
schedules:
- cron: "0 0 * * *"
  displayName: Daily midnight build
  branches:
    include:
    - main
  always: true

trigger: none
pr: none

steps:
# Azure file copy
# Copy files to Azure Blob Storage or virtual machines
- task: AzureFileCopy@4
  inputs:
    sourcePath: 
    azureSubscription: 
    destination: # Options: azureBlob, azureVMs
    storage: 
    #containerName: # Required when destination == AzureBlob
    #blobPrefix: # Optional
    #resourceGroup: # Required when destination == AzureVMs
    #resourceFilteringMethod: 'machineNames' # Optional. Options: machineNames, tags
    #machineNames: # Optional
    #vmsAdminUserName: # Required when destination == AzureVMs
    #vmsAdminPassword: # Required when destination == AzureVMs
    #targetPath: # Required when destination == AzureVMs
    #additionalArgumentsForBlobCopy: # Optional
    #additionalArgumentsForVMCopy: # Optional
    #enableCopyPrerequisites: false # Optional
    #copyFilesInParallel: true # Optional
    #cleanTargetBeforeCopy: false # Optional
    #skipCACheck: true # Optional
    #sasTokenTimeOutInMinutes: # Optional
```

Comment: Can I pass the the absolute path to my file in the `sourcePath` param?

Comment: Yes, you can. In fact if you use variable Default working directory it is absolute path behind.